# Loop Issue and duplicate result

Tags: php, loops

I have created a script to check the response header and check if it's matching and array which I have defined on it some values,

you can find the code here:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com.bh/';
    $result= get_headers($url,1);
$search = array('Strict-Transport-Security','Content-Security-Policy','X-Frame-Options','X-XSS-Protection',
        'X-Content-Type-Options','Referrer-Policy');
    //print_r($search);

     echo '<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td><b>HTTP Security Header</b></td><td><b>Header Role</b></td><td><b>Status</b></td></tr>';
    $i=0;
    foreach ($result as $key  => $v) {

    list($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f) = $search;

        if(stristr($key,$a)) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$a.'</td><td>Protects against man-in-the-middle attacks</td><td> set</td></tr>';
        }else
        echo '<tr><td>'.$a.'</td><td>Protects against man-in-the-middle attacks</td><td>Not set</td></tr>';
        if(stristr($key,$b)) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$b.'</td><td>Prevents possible phishing or XSS attacks</td><td> set</td></tr>';
        }else 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$b.'</td><td>Prevents possible phishing or XSS attacks</td><td>Not set</td></tr>';
        if(stristr($key,$c)) {
         echo '<tr><td>'.$c.'</td><td>Protects against Clickjacking attacks</td><td> set</td></tr>';
        }else 
         echo '<tr><td>'.$c.'</td><td>Protects against Clickjacking attacks</td><td>Not set</td></tr>';

        if(strstr($key,$d)) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$d.'</td><td>Mitigates Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks</td><td> set</td></tr>';
        }else 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$d.'</td><td>Mitigates Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks</td><td>Not set</td></tr>';

        if(stristr($key,$e)) {
        echo "Found".$e;
        }else 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$e.'</td><td>Prevents possible phishing or XSS attacks</td><td>Not set</td></tr>';

        if(stristr($key,$f)) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$f.'</td><td>Prevents possible phishing or XSS attacks</td><td>Not set</td></tr>';
        }else 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$f.'</td><td>Protects against Clickjacking attacks</td><td>Not set</td></tr>';
        }
```

I am expecting to give one result, But when I ran the script it gives duplicate outputs.
Please suggest whats wrong with the code
Thanks,[image]

Comment: Please include the minimal required code to reproduce the problem, and a clear statement of the problematic output vs what you expected. _'Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).'_

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your doing the tests against each header line, so your checking each header line - and then doing the set of `if...else...` conditions against all of the possibilities.  As each header can only be of one type, this means that it will fail all of the others and output that they are 'Not set'.

If instead you just check to see if that header is set in the array, it will just check it once...

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com.bh/';
$result= get_headers($url,1);
foreach ( $result as $key=>$header )  {
    $result[strtoupper($key)] = $header;
}    
$search = array('Strict-Transport-Security','Content-Security-Policy','X-Frame-Options','X-XSS-Protection',
        'X-Content-Type-Options','Referrer-Policy');
//print_r($search);

echo '<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td><b>HTTP Security Header</b></td><td><b>Header Role</b></td><td><b>Status</b></td></tr>';

list($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f) = $search;

if ( isset( $result[strtoupper($a)] )) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $a . '</td><td>Protects against man-in-the-middle attacks</td><td> set</td></tr>';
} else  {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $a . '</td><td>Protects against man-in-the-middle attacks</td><td>Not set</td></tr>';
}
```

So using `if (isset ($result[$a] )) {` checks if that header is in the list of headers from your result.  You will need to add this same code for each of the others, but hope this shows you how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nigel Ben, I found one issue with your solution if the case sensitive it won't find with isset fro example if the header response back with X-Xss-Protection and I have in the array X-XSS-Protection It won't match ... any solution with adding it to the array ?
Thanks,

Comment: You could upper case the keys.  I've updated the code to create a copy of the keys with the same values.

Comment: I appreciated your reply, I tried it and I got the fatal error:
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: Sorry - it should be `isset( $result[strtoupper($a)])`